# I had stored values of radio group in shared preference now I want to use that values for notification in android

Tags: push-notification

For example if user selects radio button for vibrate off, then on notification, vibrate must be turned off using `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Can anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple.

1.**Before display Notification**, Check the Vibrate is ON or OFF with the help of Shared Preferences.

```
SharedPreferences settings;
settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0); //Initialize SharedPreferences

Boolean CheckVibration = settings.getBoolean("CheckVibration", true); 
//checks the vibration is ON or OFF through Sharedpreferences
```

**2. Display the Notification**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
mBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
mBuilder.setContentText("Notification Testing!");

if(CheckVibration){
  long[] v = {100,200}; //The first index of array is number of milliseconds to wait before turning the vibrator on and the second index is number of millisecond to vibrate before turning it off
  mBuilder.setVibrate(v); // if vibration is ON by RadioGroup, It will be Vibrate
}


NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(notifiid, mBuilder.build());
```

3. Do not forget to allow **VIBRATE permission** in AndroidManifest.xml.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: it is good. but i don't want static.... i want settings like other proffesional chat app